# i have a single pipeline with two stages each stage must be called on two different days of week

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline

My jenkins scripted pipeline has 2 different stages one must be built on Friday and another stage must be built on Sunday...

I tried with cron job each for different stages, but I want to filter based on the day of the week, can I use any when the condition for this.?

```
node {
    
    stage('build on friday ') {
        echo "Hai its friday"
    }
        
    stage('build on sunday') {
         echo "Hai its sunday"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are always going to build them on separate days, why not separate into two jobs?

Comment: nice query here we have so many pipeline jobs in a asignle folder. , each job have its own significant purpose, creating two different jobs with unique purpose , is a bit immatured step.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I included an imperative (scripted) example using [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

#### Imperative Pipeline Example

```
node {

    def today = Calendar.getInstance();
    def dayOfWeek = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if( dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY ) {
        stage('build on friday') {
            echo "Hai its friday"
        }
    } 
                    
    if( dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY ) {
        stage('build on sunday') {
            echo "Hai its sunday"
        }
    }
}
```

> Obviously a run would need to occur on Friday and Sunday, so your cron would need to reflect that. For example: **0 1 * * 0,5**